# How to plot fitted,observed and forecast values in the same graph using R

Tags: r, time-series

So, I have a nnetar model and I want to plot my fitted, observed (actual) and forecast in the same plot with different colors and legend. It is a time-series data and "y" is my ts() object.

`fit<-nnetar(y,xreg = train_reg)`

`results<-forecast(fit,xreg = test_reg)`

`plot(results)`

With this code, I only have the forecast values and visualization, I know that I can reach the fitted ones using results$fitted and for the forecasted ones results$mean.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide example data e.g. with the lynx data set to make it reproducible

Comment: Sure, I will try to add one reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you are looking for the command `points()`.  When you run the `plot()`command, make sure to write type="n", then fill in data with the `points()`command as below

Please provide data on your next post.

Here, I have a pretend dataframe `df`that has two columns of data:

- People that voted yes (percent)
- Percent employment (meaning, how high employment is in the area)

The variables are arbitrary here, but it's just to illustrate what you want to do.

Here is the `df`

```
df <- structure(list(employment = c(23, 14.6, 9.9, 20.1, 34.4, 13.8, 
                                    20.6, 37.2, 21.8, 17.3, 13.1, 16.8, 24.6, 12.6, 13.6, 24.4, 19.3, 
                                    20, 22.6, 27.4, 23.1, 10.7, 32.1, 22, 25.6, 25), yes = c(55.2, 
                                                                                             54.4, 63.5, 50.6, 39, 51.1, 48.5, 39.1, 59.4, 50.6, 44.1, 53.3, 
                                                                                             39.3, 58.8, 59.1, 58.1, 63.1, 54.6, 55.9, 68.2, 57.8, 58.2, 38.9, 
                                                                                             48.3, 49.9, 47.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L
                                                                                             ))
```

Run your model and add fitted values to your `df`

```
model<-lm(yes ~ employment, data = df)

df$fit <-predict(model) # add fitted, aka predicted, values to df

attach(df)
```

- we can also add confidence intervals to the plot using the code below
  & you can shade in the confidence intervals if you wish with the polygon command

lets make a custom transparent color using `library(yarr)` and the function `function yarr::transparent()`

```
library(yarrr)

par(mfrow = c(1, 1), cex=2, pch=10) # set plot window to desired conditions
plot(yes ~ employment, data = df, ylab = "Yes [%]", xlab="Employment [%]", type="n")
points(yes ~ employment)
points(fit~employment, col="red") # Note, these are the fitted values in red
newx <- seq(min(df$employment), max(df$employment), length.out=100)
preds <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(employment=newx), interval = 'confidence')
polygon(c(rev(newx), newx), c(rev(preds[ ,3]), preds[ ,2]), col = yarrr::transparent("583", trans.val = .5), border = NA)
abline(lm(yes~foreigners),col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(newx, preds[ ,3], lty = 'dashed', col = 'blue', lwd=2)
lines(newx, preds[ ,2], lty = 'dashed', col = 'blue',lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, was educative enough! but how can I produce exactly something like this for the forecasting process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM8Ak.jpg

Comment: well you really need to provide data if you need help with that specific example

But it's the same process, and your model should look like

```model <- lm(MSW-R4 ~Time, data=df)```and then follow above steps with adding predicted (fitted) data to your df, and use the same plot command

Comment: thank you! I also fixed the problem using autoplot+autolayer

Comment: @binaryskull glad I could help.  Could you please upvote my answer if it worked out for you?

Comment: okay I did it now :)